# Delphi - form within form

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

For aesthetic reasons, I want to show a form on top of another form, just as if it were a component, say like a TPanel. It should resize with the parent, move around as the parent is dragged by its title bar, etc.

```
-----------------------------
| main form component 1     |
-----------------------------
| main |  the 'embedded'    |  
| form |  form goes here    |
|comp 2|                    |
-----------------------------
```

can I do that? If so how?

---

I am now leaning towards MDI...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340318/how-can-i-visually-design-a-component-in-c-builder.

Comment: We call that "docking" (embedded form goes here).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put a panel where you want your embedded form to be at design time. At run time, Create the form, then set the embedded form's Parent property to the panel.

```
procedure TParentForm.FormCreate(ASender: TObject);
begin
  FEmbeddedForm := TEmbeddedForm.Create(self);

  FEmbeddedForm.Parent := Panel1;
  FEmbeddedForm.Align := alClient;
  FEmbeddedForm.Visible := True;

end;
```

**Edit:**

If you want to stop the window title and border from being displayed, add this to the bottom of the `FormCreate()`

```
  LForm.Caption := '';
  LForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
```

BTW, I am not advocating using parented forms over frames, just answering the question. Frames are great (I use them all the time), but they are not *exactly* the same as Forms. They are almost exactly like a panel with controls on it.

For instance, a frame does not have an OnCreate event, nor an OnShow event, which can be painful sometimes when you are reusing them and need that sort of behavior.

N@

Comment: @Nat: .Parent takes a TWinControl, not a WindowHandle. I took the liberty to fix your code.

Comment: Anyone know if setting Parent differs in any way from TForm.ManualDock with align=alClient?

Comment: @Fransois: Thanks! You are dead right! The end of a long week...
@Warran P: `ManualDoc()` can have interesting effects, I keep to setting Parent unless I really am 'docking' a form.

Comment: and Frame does not have an independent alphablend property

Comment: EDIT: I was wrong! alphablend property of the embedded form is just ignored.

Comment: You use frames all the time means I am going to use them all the time too. thanks Nat.

Comment: Where to place the components: On the first form, on the second form FEmbeddedForm, or on the panel ??

Answer (score 14):

You could use a [frame](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TFrame.html).

Answer (score 3):

Native win32 MDI is considered "out of date". I think you might be looking for something like the JEDI JvDocking library.  I use it to emulate MDI but without using the win32 MDI support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (+1). I am using TMS components & don't want to mix too much 3rd party stuff. I will try the suggestion of putting it on a panel.